# Display Array Object With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want displaying object data in table, which value inside name of object appear as `<td>`,
i have result in the network preview like this below:

[image]

I need displaying value inside `A1_score` and `A2_score` as `<td>`, so i tried jquery like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cektesting', function(e) {
$('.row').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'none' });
$.ajax({
    url: "pengguna/getCounting",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.row').css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'display': 'flex' });
        $.each(data['A1_score', 'A2_score'], function(key, value) {
            $('#tbodyres').append(
                '<tr id="idscore"><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr> '
            );
        });
    }
});
});
```

And last thing those data came from my `Controller.php`:

```
 public function getCounting()
{
    $get_row_class = $this->getdata->getAutism();
    $get_row = $this->getdata->countrow();

    $row_autism = $get_row_class['Autism'];
    $row_normal = $get_row_class['Normal'];

    $res_autism = number_format($row_autism / $get_row['jml_data_latih'], 6);
    $res_normal = number_format($row_normal / $get_row['jml_data_latih'], 6);

    $A_Score = $this->getdata->getA_score();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($A_Score as $as) {
        $row['A_Y_NORMAL'] = $as['A1_YES_NORMAL'] / $row_normal;
        $row['A_Y_AUTIS'] = $as['A1_YES_AUTIS']  / $row_autism;
        $row['A_N_NORMAL'] = $as['A1_NO_NORMAL']  / $row_normal;
        $row['A_N_AUTIS'] = $as['A1_NO_AUTIS']  / $row_autism;

        $row2['A_Y_NORMAL'] = $as['A2_YES_NORMAL'] / $row_normal;
        $row2['A_Y_AUTIS'] = $as['A2_YES_AUTIS'] / $row_autism;
        $row2['A_N_NORMAL'] = $as['A2_NO_NORMAL'] / $row_normal;
        $row2['A_N_AUTIS'] = $as['A2_NO_AUTIS'] / $row_autism;


        $data['A1_score'] = $row;
        $data['A2_score'] = $row2;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**Result:**
And this is what i get when i tried build jquery from jquery code above, So i get `A2_score` data but `A1_score` didn't displaying only `A2_score` data get looped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all `keys` inside your object and then use that keys to get required data from both *JSON Object* .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo..
var data = {
  "A1_score": {
    "xs": 12322,
    "sse": 1232
  },
  "A2_score": {
    "xs": 1234,
    "sse": 213
  }
}
//get keys of one object because keys in other object are same
var keys = Object.keys(data["A1_score"])
console.log(keys)
//loop through keys 
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var keys_ = keys[i]
  //add that inside your table
  $('#tbodyres').append(
    '<tr class="idscore"><td>' + keys_ + '</td><td>' + data["A1_score"][keys_] + '</td><td>' + data["A2_score"][keys_] + '</td></tr> '
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbodyres"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `data['A1_score', 'A2_score']` to iterate over properties `A1_score` & `A2_score`. What you should do is iterate over either `A1_score` or `A2_score` and retrieve `key`. Then get values from `A1_score` & `A1_score` with `data["A1_score"][key]` & `data["A2_score"][key]`.

Try like below.

```
$.each(data["A1_score"], function(key, value) {
    $('#tbodyres').append(
        '<tr id="idscore"><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + data["A1_score"][key] + '</td><td>' + data["A2_score"][key] + '</td></tr> '
    );
});
```

Comment: its displayed, but `A2_score` values didnt displayed as `<td>` but new `<tr>`, what i expected is the values of `A1_score` and `A2_score` displayed side by side with `<td>`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try now.